# Turn two queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some problems with a query I'm writing. This seems like table structure that is very frequent so I'd love some help.

Let's say I have 3 tables similar to a facebook structure. `Users`, `Wall Posts`, and `Comments`. Users can make wall posts, and comment on other wall posts.

On a users page I would like to show a users wall posts and a count of how many comments that post has. This is what I have so far

I query the `Wall Post` table using the users id as an inner join to the `User` table. That gives me a result set of wall posts for that user's page. Then I loop through that result set, take the Wall Post id from each result set, and query the `Comment` table for the Count of comments for that Wall Post Id. This works, however I have to hit the db twice. Can anyone think of a way that I could do this with one query?

First Query Example:

```
SELECT wallPost.*, user.currentDefault, user.displayName, user.userName 
FROM wallPost 
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = wallPost.sourceUserId 
WHERE wallPost.recipientId = ? ORDER BY wallPost.id DESC
```

Second Query Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count 
FROM comment 
WHERE wallPostId = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the count as a subquery and join the subquery to the main query

```
SELECT
    wallPost.*,
    user.currentDefault,
    user.displayName,
    user.userName,
    wallpost_commentcount.total
FROM
    wallPost
        INNER JOIN user ON user.id=wallPost.sourceUserId
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT wallPostId,COUNT(*) as total FROM comment GROUP BY wallPostId) as wallpost_commentcount ON (wallpost_commentcount.wallPostId=wallPost.id)
WHERE
    wallPost.recipientId = ?
ORDER BY wallPost.id DESC
```

Please make sure you have an index on `comment.wallPostId` otherwise this query will take a long time.

I used the `LEFT JOIN` because you always want to get the wallPost even if there are no comments records yet

Comment: First off you're a genius. I need some help understanding this though. First, why the group by? Can't you just use count to get the count?

Comment: If you run the subquery by itself you'll understand why - you are getting all of the wallposts and the COUNT() of comments per wallpost and then joining that result set on the outer query

Comment: @gmustudent: You want to count per `wallPostId`, not everything in the table `comment`, so you need to add `GROUP BY wallPostId` - at least according to the SQL standard.

Comment: Why did you not need to put a table name after the left join? I'm referencing w3schools like crazy trying to understand this one and they put a table name after the join.

Comment: re the `LEFT JOIN` - the "as wallpost_commentcount" is the aliased table name. This tells SQL that I want the results of the query in parens to be treated as a table for the rest of the query

Comment: I've learned so much from this simple post and have rewritten it a couple times to make sure I really get it. Thank you so much for your assistance I really appreciate it